# Copy file from Puppet master to agent unless software is installed

Tags: ruby, puppet

**execution of exec or package types by puppet master controllable**

Installation of package X on linux, unless X has been installed already:

```
package { "X": }
```

&&

Installation of executable Y on Windows, unless Y has been installed already:

```
exec { "packageYInstalled":
    command => "packageY /S",
    require => "C:\\temp\\packageY",
    unless => "packageYinstalled";
}
```

**Execution of file type by puppet master uncontrollable as unless attribute is not allowed in puppet file type**

[puppet file attributes](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file)

```
file { "packageYCopiedToTempFolder": }
    path => "C:\\temp\\packageY",
    source => "puppet:///files/packageY";
}
```

**Execute installers from shared (samba) folder instead of copy it first to agent system does not solve the issue**

- Puppet runs executed on multiple external systems
- Executables, zips and or tar.gz packages are copied to the remote systems during every puppet run, while these files where removed after installation and software has been installed already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i tackle this, and there might be a better ways to do this :

1. Create a module for installing the product
2. In that module, write a custom fact for discovering the version installed
3. In the installer class, wrap everything in an 'if'

i.e.

```
class productx::install (
  $version,
  $installer_path,
) {
  # productx_version is a fact
  if ! $::productx_version {
    do the install
  }
}
```

You can do other neat stuff then, like audit the software in your environment

Comment: Thank you. I am currently busy to make this work and let you know the outcome.

Comment: I have created a custom fact in /modules/X/lib/facter/Y.rb and wrote the command I used as an `unless` attribute in the `exec` type, in ruby. If the if results in NOT a true the installation will be done. Thank you for the solution. The puppet runs will be completed faster as the check is executed once instead of multiple times by the unless attributes. I will accept the answer and I would like to vote up the answer as well, but reputation 15 is required and I only have 3.